Example of Coalgebras Without Any Nonzero Cocommutative Elements?
It is known that every coalgebra in characteristic $0$ has a nonzero cocommutative element: find a finite dimensional subcoalgebra, express it as a quotient of some comatrix coalgebra $C_n$, and take the image of the diagonal $d = \sum_i e_{i,i}$. The image is nonzero as $\epsilon d = n \neq 0$ in characteristic $0$. The question is, are there any coalgebras in positive characteristic that do not admit any nonzero cocommutative elements? I tried quotienting $C_p$ over $\mathbb{Z/pZ}$ with the coideal generated by $d$, but that does not seem to work. The direction should be right...
